# Fetch new posts from facebook using Graph API

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, spring-social-facebook

I am using Graph API to authorize a user with my app to fetch posts from their timeline and from their liked pages.

I'm able to fetch all posts and save them. But, when I fetch again after a period of time it includes both the new posts and old ones which creates duplicate entries. I only want the new posts which are not fetched yet. I know about the [webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks) in facebook. But, I want to know any other way to do this just like twitter (using `since_id`).

NB: I'm using [spring-social-facebook](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook) for these operations.

Looking for some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can use `since` and `until` parameters to filter the results. Try this call: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/135669679827333/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed%3Fsince%3D1%20january%202017%26until%3Dnow&version=v2.5

You can store your `lastUpdateDate` and then use `since` lastUpdateDate `until` now.